# Intellij doesn't host static content

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, intellij-idea

I'm trying to migrate from Eclipse to Intellij, and I've encountered what seems like a strange issue. When I run the project through Eclipse, my static content (index.html) is accessible, but when I run it through Intellij, it is not.

In eclipse, I use a Maven Build with the goals `jetty:run` and profiles `dev`. I can then access my content through the url `http://localhost:8080/last-galaxy/ui/index.html`.

In intellij, I use a Maven run with the command line `jetty:run` and profiles `dev`. And I then cannot access content through that url.

So what could possibly be the difference here? I'm setting up that static content through Spring, and I'm not sure how that could work differently from Eclipse to Intellij.

My spring config that wires up that content is:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(SpringConfig.BASE_PACKAGE)
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories(SpringConfig.BASE_PACKAGE)
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

    /**
     * You probably shouldn't change the base package name, but if you do, update it in here!
     */
    protected static final String BASE_PACKAGE = "com.corinthgames.lastgalaxy";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/ui/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I'd look for is to print the runtime classpath and see whether IDEA is supplying the Maven dependencies via the on-disk project as M2E does or via jars which won't reflect changes.

Comment: Well, it magically started working. I think you're right, though, because now I have the issue that my javascript files don't automatically reflect changes I make.